# Backing light for clock gone

Tags: lights

The backing light to the clock of my Nissan Pulsar ST1.8 has gone. I've checked the fuses and they all seem fine. How should I go about fixing it?

Here are some pictures:

[image: With no flash you can't see the clock in the bottom rhs]

[image: With the flash you can clearly see the clock isn't illuminated]

Answer (score 1):

Consider calling the local Nissan parts department, and see if this is even possible. I know some manufacturers don't support changing bulbs inside of the dash, but I could be wrong as far as nissan is concerned. If you do decide to go forth, and find a bulb, ensure to remove the battery cable before pulling the dash. Most cars have buses that run thorugh the dash, and you would hate to trigger a fault.

Comment: Usually those LCD screens are lit on the edge by LEDs, so most likely you would have to do some soldering to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the backlighting is serviceable separately. I would search for rebuild kits, I have found several on eBay with the components and instructions on how to repair it. You can also goggle instrument panel repair service and find other options